# Box2d polygon skin

Tags: box2d

[In manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html) is see:

> Polygons inherit a radius from b2Shape. The radius creates a skin
>   around the polygon. The skin is used in stacking scenarios to keep
>   polygons slightly separated. This allows continuous collision to work
>   against the core polygon. The polygon skin helps prevent tunneling by
>   keeping the polygons separated.

From this I don't understand what problem is being solved with the skin? What if there were not skins, what would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polygon skin is used in Continuous Collision Detection (CCD) and is something internal to Box2D.

As says Erin Catto:

> Polygon skin is a buffer for continuous collision detection. CCD
> breaks down when shapes overlap. Need a small separation. You
> shouldn't need to tune it if you use meters.

Here is [more information how CCD works in Box2D](https://t.co/Lhm48f0fwZ).